# GridView e Linq to SQL

Tags: gridview, linq-to-sql

estou tentando alterar dados em um GridView utilizando um DataSource Linq to SQL Context:

Criei uma tabela no SQL:
BancoID int Autoincremento
BancoNumero char(3)
BancoNome varchar(30)

Criei uma classe Linq to SQL e inclui o acesso para essa tabela.

Na janela de Fonte de Dados fiz a leitura do Objeto Data Context para minha tabela.
Criei um formulário e adicionei um DataGridView.
No DataGridView alterei o Datasource para esta conexão da fonte de dados.

O DataGridView reconheceu as colunas da minha tabela.

Na seleção foi criado automaticamente um System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource

Quando executo e tento adicionar dados na tabela, no DataGridView é como se os dados estivessem sendo adicionados, exceto pelo BancoID que fica sempre com valor 0.

Mas quando fecho o formulário e abro de novo vejo que os dados não foram gravados na tabela do SQL.

O que é necessário fazer para funcionar?

Comment: Após as alterações você persistiu essas alterações feitas no banco de dados?

Comment: Estou migrando do VB6 e aprendendo C# agora. No VB6 isso era automático. Qual o caminho que devo percorrer para ter os dados salvos em minha tabela? Gostaria de editar as colunas diretamente no DataGridView.

Comment: Seria no seu contexto de dados usar o metodo **SaveChanges()**

Neste link tem um exemplo 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766417/save-changes-in-linq-to-sql

Mas cada caso pode exigir alguns aspectos no que tange o contexto observando as mudanças.

Como não teve nenhum código sobre como foi feito fica complicado ajudar de uma forma melhor